# Retrieving a lost string from a trie

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, trie

On exam on data structures I did see the following question:

A suffix trie is given.
Now I know that that a trie only holds pointers with specific indexes to an array of chars.

Now they claim that the original string is lost, and I should find the string only using the trie. 
I can't understand, how is that possible?

Comment: If trie contains single string entry, you can find it by following non-null array entries.

Comment: indeed the trie holds a single string, can you elaborate?

Comment: You should understand trie structure - it's modified tree where each node contains array (lets say 26 for each letter) of pointers to next level nodes. Following these relations by scanning arrays you can see what words are held inside it.

Comment: The original string can be obtained by finding the deepest leaf in the trie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A suffix trie is a special data structure that can be viewed as an automaton.
Since this is a suffix *trie* and not a suffix *tree*, each substring of the original string has an explicit state in the *trie* that represents it.

Any leaf of the *trie* will represent a specific suffix of the original string. Since the original string is the longest suffix of itself, **there is a leaf in the trie that represents the original string, and it is the deepest leaf in the trie.**

To recover the original string, you just have to conduct a *BFS* starting from the root until you find this deepest leaf. The complexity will be *O(N²)* where *N* is the length of the original string (because the number of nodes in a suffix trie is *O(N²)*).

---

EDIT: After being downvoted, I insist on the fact that we are working on a **suffix trie**, *NOT* a **suffix tree**. These data structures are similar, true, but they are *NOT* the same! A suffix trie represents explicitly *EVERY* substring of its original string. A suffix tree on the other hand only represents the *branching states* of the suffix trie.

Now, how many distinct substrings can there be in a string? 1 substring of length *N*, 2 of length *N-1*, 3 of length *N-2*,... Total *N(N+1)/2* = *O(N²)*.

Comment: To the downvoter: you misread. A suffix **tree** will have a linear complexity. On the other hand, a suffix **trie** can contain up to _O(N²)_ nodes... So building it (or exploring it) involves a quadractic complexity... See [this](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ukkonen/SuffixT1withFigs.pdf) to convice yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can feed the suffix tree with a similar string and a wildcard. I know its possible with the longest subsequence and aho-corasick algorithm.